# obtener datos de una activity desde un fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

tengo una actividad la cual llama a un fragment para mostrar los datos con ayuda de jetpack composer, esta actividad recibe los datos de un usuario y quiero que esos datos se pasen al fragment para que los muestre.

la actividad principal es la siguiente

```
class Main : AappCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstaceState: Bundle?){
        val bundle:Bundle? = intent.extras
        val email: String? = bundle?.getString("email")

        //aqui inicializo el fragment
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.compose_view,MyFragment())
            .comit()
    }
}
```

y este es el codigo de MyFragment

```
class Fragment : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: layoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstaceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = ComposeView(requireContext())
        view.apply {
            setContent {
                //funcion composable
                Text(text=user)//usuario obtenido de la activity
            }
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

he encontrado formas de pasar datos entre fragments pero no obtener los datos de una activity desde el fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**opción 1: pasarlo como argumento**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstaceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstaceState)
        val email: String? = intent.extras?.getString("email")
        val fragment = MyFragment().apply {
            arguments = bundleOf("user" to email)
        }
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.compose_view, fragment)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        val user = arguments?.getString("user")
        setContent {
            if (user!= null) Text(user)
        }
    }
}
```

**opción 2: crear una propiedad pública y leerla desde el fragment**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var user: String? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstaceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstaceState)
        user = intent.extras?.getString("email")
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.compose_view, MyFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        val user = (activity as MainActivity).user
        setContent {
            if (user!= null) Text(user)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eres mi salvador, de verdad muchas gracias