# ¿Como llamar un activity desde un fragment en kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que tengo una barlayout con varios fragments, y en uno de ellos tengo un botón que al pulsarlo llama a un activity, pero no me funciona.

Este es el código del fragment que llama al activity:

```kotlin
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)

        //setup
        setup()
    }

    private fun setup(){

        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener {
            val editProfileIntent = Intent(this, EditProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(editProfileIntent)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/434442/183782) te puede servir

Comment: Que no funciona, se cierra? me parece que es el contexto de hecho no se esta usando correctamente, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de usar como contexto la `Activity` que contiene el actual `Fragment`, eso se logra mediante el uso de `getActivity()`, usalo como contexto para inicializar el intent :

```
editProfileButton.setOnClickListener {
            val editProfileIntent = Intent(getActivity(), EditProfileActivity::class.java)
            getActivity().startActivity(editProfileIntent)
        }
```

---

Con respecto a el otro error que comentas:

> Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference

Si revisas tu còdigo no estas obteniendo la referencia del boton `editProfileButton` en tu layout fragment_profile.xml

Para obtener la referencia lo puedes realizar en el mètodo

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        editProfileButton = view.findViewById(R.id.iddelboton)
       
}
```

Revisa este ejemplo:

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/common-patterns?hl=es#fragment-nullability

Comment: Lo he probado así como dices y me da este error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Bueno ese es otro error, la referencia del botòn editProfileButton no existe porque no estas obteniendo la referencia del layout fragment_profile.xml

Comment: Como puedo hacer eso? He intentado hacerlo con el findViewById pero me sale como que no existe ese método.

Comment: Agregue una actualizaciòn solo define el id correcto del boton en el layout en lugar de "iddelboton".

Comment: Muchas gracias ya sirvió

Comment: Excelente Raul ,saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu código ni siquiera pordría compilar porque el contructor de la clase `Intent` necesita como primer argumento un `Context` y le estás pasando `this` que es un `Fragment`. Puedes solucionarlo pasandole la activity que hostea al fragment

```
val editProfileIntent = Intent(activity, EditProfileActivity::class.java)
```

Aparte de eso, el método `setup` nunca se va a ejecutar porque lo estás llamando después de un `return`. Esta instrucción finaliza la función en ejecución y por lo tanto todo el código que le siga es ignorado. Tampoco puedes invocar `setup()` antes de inflar el layout porque no te permitiría acceder el botón. Es decir que debes llamarlo entre esas dos instrucciones

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    setup()
    return view
}
```

Aunque tal vez sea más claro en `onViewCreated`

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_profile) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener {
            val editProfileIntent = Intent(activity, EditProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(editProfileIntent)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Lo he probado así como dices y me da este error:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: edita tu pregunta con el código actualizado